# Typescript falls back to the default value of generic type for no reason

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the title is not very obvious. I don't know what is the problem so I couldn't come up with a good question. This is a simplified version of the problem that I'm struggling with:

```js
type Key = unknown[];

type Option<TKey extends Key> = {
  key: TKey;
  updateKey: (v: TKey) => TKey;
};

type Getter = <Value>(v: Value) => Value

function createConfigWithOption<TKey extends Key>(
  getOptions: ((g: Getter) => Option<TKey>)
) {
}
```

`createConfigWithOption` receives a function whose first parameter is a getter function (doesn't matter what it does) and returns an option object. The option object has a `key` key and an `updateKey` function. The input and output of `updateKey` should be inferred from the `key`.

It works correctly if I don't use the getter:

```js
createConfigWithOption(() => ({
  key: ["1"],
  updateKey: (currentKey) => {
    const a = currentKey[0];
    //    ^? const a: string

    return [];
  },
}));
```

But it falls back to the default value of `Key` when I use the getter:

```js
createConfigWithOption((get) => ({
  key: ["1"],
  updateKey: (currentKey) => {
    const a = currentKey[0];
    //    ^? const a: unknown
    
    return [];
  },
}));
```

Here is a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQK4DsDWaD2B3NA2gLoDcAsAFCWiRQDyYwAltmgDwAqcCEAHsBDQATAM6x4APiRQA3pShQM8AFxQu8chQUowQgIYDuqgBQA3VepABKJFMuaAvpurhoAcQjABAJ2lsAanoANigQEmaqgSEQNohSUaGUlABm6ADGzKxQad4QBhAAwqzJTADmAOpMwAAWDJnsllB8AsJi3OHyUKWedSxoIibGpaoeXhDesVK9rJztVpQ2chQOSRQ5eQJFaCUVVbWMfcbGk1DGSwpKIKoEAEQAjDdEADSdOvqGKqdpKN65aMDcE7nBTZVgiYBQPTSb6-QQA%20AEAAMpE6CgA9GiQVAAHoAflWWNywB%20aCgxE0CgcL2WViszjWuXyWx2lRq0zQR26wBOZ06l2u90e1O0unyRi%20Pz%208OstlkqNB-QhUOQMKl3CRKK0IIxWLx8vlRJJZM1lOpDlpJCAA) if you want to try it out yourself.

I've been scratching my head for several hours to understand what's going on but didn't find an answer.

Comment: What are you going to use `get` for? The type of `get` is currently what's known as the identity function, which I don't think is very useful in this context.

Comment: Your problem can be simplified to https://tsplay.dev/m0YjPW

Comment: What's going on is as described in [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599); by putting `get` in there without annotating it, it is making the function context-sensitive (it needs to infer the type for `get`) and this gets in the way, since it has to infer the type parameter first, but it can't infer the type parameter without knowing the return type of the callback, and it essentially gives up.  There have been some improvements but your case is still unfixed.  Does that fully address your q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I think that's the problem. Thank you so much. I would appreciate it if you write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) for an authoritative description of this issue.

TypeScript's [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) algorithm isn't perfect by any means; it's effectively a collection of heuristic rules that works well over a wide range of use cases, but there are unfortunately situations where it fails to infer something that a human developer would see as obvious.  One place where things can go awry is if the compiler needs to infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments at the same time it needs to [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) callback parameter types.

The difference between

```
createConfigWithOption(() => ({
  key: ["1"],
  updateKey: (currentKey) => {
    const a = currentKey[0];
    //    ^? const a: string

    return [];
  },
}));
```

and

```
createConfigWithOption((get) => ({
  key: ["1"],
  updateKey: (currentKey) => {
    const a = currentKey[0];
    //    ^? const a: unknown
    
    return [];
  },
}));
```

is that in the latter, the callback passed to `createConfigWithOption` has a callback parameter `get` whose type the compiler wants to infer for you.  That makes the whole callback function *context sensitive*.  Generally speaking, if the compiler doesn't know the parameter type of a function, it can't know the types of what's going on inside the function either.  The current algorithm tends to delay context sensitive inferences until after generic type arguments are inferred.  But this is a problem, since leaving the callback as a black box means that the compiler has no idea what to infer for the `E` generic type parameter, so it falls back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), after which `get` is inferred properly... but it's too late, since `E` is wider than you want.

Note that in this particular instance, it turns out that `get` is not *used* anywhere inside the function body, so in fact nothing *actually* depends on its type.  But the compiler doesn't do much of an inspection into the function body to check for that sort of thing.  So using `(get)=>` like that messes up inference for you.

---

So that's what's going on.  There have been recent improvements in this sort of circular contextual-and-generic inference, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538), but they can't address every possible situation, and your code is one of those places that still doesn't work as you want.

The workarounds here are either to leave it out entirely like `()=>` as in your first example, or to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) it with its type so the compiler doesn't have to infer it:

```
createConfigWithOption((get: Getter) => ({
  key: ["1"],
  updateKey: (currentKey) => {
    const a = currentKey[0];
    //    ^? const a: string
    
    return [];
  },
}));
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQK4DsDWaD2B3NA2gLoDcAsAFCWiRQDyYwAltmgDwAqcCEAHsBDQATAM6x4APiRQA3pShQM8AFxQu8chQUowQgIYDuqgBQA3VepABKJFMuaAvpurhoAcQjABAJ2lsAanoANigQEmaqgSEQNohSUaGUlABm6ADGzKxQad4QBhAAwqzJTADmAOpMwAAWDJnsllB8AsJi3OHyUKWedSxoIibGpaoeXhDesVK9rJztVpQ2chQOSRQ5eQJFaCUVVbWMfcbGk1DGSwpKIKoEAEQAjDdEADSdOvqGKqdpKN65aMDcE7nBTZVgiYBQPTSb6-QQA+AEAAMpE6CgA9GiQVAAHoAflWWNywB+aCgxE0CgcL2WViszjWuXyWx2lRq0zQR26wBOZ06l2u90e1O0unyRi+Pz+8OstlkqNB-QhUOQMKl3CRKK0IIxWLx8vlRJJZM1lOpDlp9PWTOKZVZ+3qnM8I08Ph5wP5ZMFz1eoo+VwlsP+gNlwIUaTBSuhkrh6uRFO1mJBeq1CgNniN5M6VMo5rpQA)